# How to log using NLog directly to Datadog

Tags: logging, nlog, datadog

Using Nlog to log from my asp.net Core application, I would like to review the logs in Datadog.

Datadog allows me to visualize the log data, and slice, search, select and sort logs in a convenient way to provide support to my customers.

I was looking for a way to use NLog to directly post to the Datadog API, so I do not need to use the Windows Agent to collect the logs.

Below how to do this, as I could not find the answer anywhere.

Comment: If you're using Docker you can use APM https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/csharp/?tab=nlog#agentless-logging-with-apm

Answer (score 4):

In Datadog, create an API key in Integrations, APIs. Give the API key a name.

In NLog.config create a target. The url is either datadoghq.com or datadoghq.eu (for europe).

```
 <target xsi:type="WebService"
        name="datadog"
        url="https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/v1/input"
        encoding="utf-8"
        protocol="JsonPost"
        preAuthenticate="false" >
        <parameter name='date' type='System.String' layout='${longdate}'/> 
        <parameter name='ipaddress' type='System.String' layout='${aspnet-request-ip}'/>
        <parameter name="userid" type='System.String' layout="${aspnet-User-Identity}" />
        <parameter name="level"  type='System.String'  layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <parameter name="version" type='System.String'  layout="${configsetting:name=VersionSettings.Version:default=?}" />
        <parameter name="threadid"  type='System.String' layout="${threadid}" />
        <parameter name="controller"  type='System.String' layout="${aspnet-mvc-controller}" />
        <parameter name="class" type='System.String'  layout="${callsite:className=True:includeNamespace=False:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True:cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates=True:cleanNamesOfAsyncContinuations=True}" />
        <parameter name="message" type='System.String'  layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="elapsed"  type='System.String' layout ="${event-properties:item=elapsed}" />
        <parameter name="service"  type='System.String' layout="${configsetting:name=Nlog.Component}" />
        <parameter name="hostname"  type='System.String' layout="${configsetting:name=Nlog.HostName}" />
        <parameter name="exception"  type='System.String' layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
        <parameter name="ddsource"  type='System.String' layout="csharp" />
        <header name="DD-API-KEY" layout="${configsetting:name=Nlog.datadog}"/>
        <header name="Content-Type" layout="application/json"/>
</target>
```

Now create a rule to write to the target and you are done!

All of the parameters can be configured to become columns in Datadog, and/or facets to select on. I am using a date parameter so that the date matches other logs, rather than displaying the built in date.

Comment: See also: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nlog.Sinks.Datadog.Logs/

Comment: Thank you, I saw that, but there is no documentation, I don't know if I can use the layouts like I did in this example above. 
Do you think there is a benefit of using that above the WebService, or are you just providing the pointer to have a look? 
Thanks anyway.

Comment: No sadly enough the guy that implemented the NLog-target did not add support for configuring LogFormatter-attributes from NLog.config.

Comment: Hi @PietervanKampen, I'm getting the following internal nlog error. Any ideas? Thanks:- Error WebService Target[datadog]: Error has been raised. Exception: System.ArgumentException: The 'Content-Type' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.

Comment: @PietervanKampen, also, just want to clarify, "DD-API-KEY" is the name you defined for the API key in Integrations? Thanks!

Comment: @TokyoD did you add the Content-Type header in the target? Also  modify the url for the datadog api, if you use the https://app.datadoghq.eu/ location to access the dashboard.

The DD-API-KEY is the name of the header that Datadog expects, see
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/build-custom-reports-using-log-analytics-api/?tab=table

Comment: @PietervanKampen, Yes I copy/pasted the exact config above, it didn't seem to like the 'Content-Type' setting. When I removed it completely the error went away but no logging (and no internal nlog error either). Anyway, all good now. I switched to www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Target.Datadog which works well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of Pieter's answer(which was really helpful!) if you prefer to specify the datadog parameters in your code instead of in an XML file:

```
//create a web service target
var datadog = new NLog.Targets.WebServiceTarget("datadog");

//adjust to your specific url (I'm on US-5 here)
datadog.Url = "https://http-intake.logs.us5.datadoghq.com/v1/input";
datadog.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
datadog.Protocol = WebServiceProtocol.JsonPost;
datadog.PreAuthenticate = false;
    
//define parameters here
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("date", Layout.FromString("${longdate}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("ipaddress", Layout.FromString("${aspnet-request-ip}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("userid", Layout.FromString("${aspnet-User-Identity}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("level", Layout.FromString("${level:upperCase=true}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("version", Layout.FromString("${configsetting:name=VersionSettings.Version:default=?}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("threadid", Layout.FromString("${threadid}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("controller", Layout.FromString("${aspnet-mvc-controller}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("class", Layout.FromString("${callsite:className=True:includeNamespace=False:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True:cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates=True:cleanNamesOfAsyncContinuations=True}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("message", Layout.FromString("${message}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("elapsed", Layout.FromString("${event-properties:item=elapsed}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("service", Layout.FromString(component), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("hostname", Layout.FromString(host), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("exception", Layout.FromString("${exception:format=ToString}"), typeof(String)));
datadog.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("ddsource", Layout.FromString("csharp"), typeof(String)));

//replace with your actual API key
datadog.Headers.Add(new MethodCallParameter("DD-API-KEY", Layout.FromString(datadogKey)));
datadog.Headers.Add(new MethodCallParameter("Content-Type", Layout.FromString("application/json")));
                    
//add rule
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, datadog);
//finally add the config to NLog
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Datadog provides API key. It is available under profile section on your organisation datadog site. Refer screenshot.

[image]

Now the next step is to add Datadog target in Nlog.Config file. You need to provide apiKey and source in below configuration. Source could be an unique application name.

```
 <target xsi:type="Datadog" name="dataDog" layout="${longdate} ${newline} ${event-properties:item=UserName} 
        ${newline} ${message} ${newline} ${exception:format=tostring} ${newline}" includeAllProperties="true"
      apiKey="your-api-key" source="your-application-name"/>
```

Pass Rules under rules section in Nlog.config file for datadog

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="datadog" />
```

After performing above steps, you are ready to log exception/log.

You can check log/exception under Logs menu in datadog.
Go to Logs->Search and on source section, just search application name that you have mentioned in Nlog file as source.

I have also generated some errors using Nlog DataDog. You can see in the screenshot. Please refer it.
[image]

I hope this answer will help you.